# how to implement drag and drop in html5 and java?

Tags: java, jquery, drag-and-drop

So Basically I need to implement a drag and drop functionality to a simple project of mine.  I found a tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljTsSkU8ecM which was quite fine but the problem was that His server-side code was in php and mine was in java. Well I did implemented my server-side in java but at the end while opening file it says it is corrupted.

Here is what i'm doing:
Client-side:

```
obj.on('dragover', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid #16a085');
});
obj.on('drop', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid #16a085');
    var files=e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    var file=files[0];
    upload(file);
});

function upload(file){
    xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('post','../servlet',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.fileName);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-File-Size',file.fileSize);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type',file.fileType);
    xhr.send(file);
}
```

Server-side:

```
String datareceived = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
System.out.println(datareceived);
byte data[] = datareceived.getBytes();
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:/new/im.jpg");
output.write(data);
output.close();
```

What I noticed with comparing original file and uploaded file with notepad++ was that the uploaded file had replaced the `end-of-line` with `?`. I also tried

```
String DecodedData = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(datareceived, "UTF-8");
```

And beside that I also tried:

```
 for(Part p : request.getParts() ) {
        InputStream filecontent = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        output = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/new/im.jpg"));
        filecontent = p.getInputStream();
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;

        while((read = filecontent.read(bytes))!=-1){
            output.write(bytes,0,read);
        }
        output.close();
    }
```

But this pop an exception saying:

> java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2863)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2699)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1096)
>       at duck.reg.pack.uploadtostack.doPost(uploadtostack.java:25)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:840)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2791)
>       ... 27 more

But that was giving me an Illegal exception. I don't really know what am I doing wrong and I would really appreciate if somebody tell me what is the right way of doing it.
Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: Since the request’s content type is `multipart/form-data`, you need to read the request in that format.  Use [request.getParts](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts--), not getReader.  I assume the first Part is the data you want to save;  use [Part.write](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#write-java.lang.String-) to save it to a file.

Comment: Thanks for reply Bro. It tried the way you said but that's giving me an exception. You can read it in my question I just updated it.

Comment: I don’t have any experience with doing AJAX calls directly from the client side, but [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) says that `send(file)` only uses the file as the body of the message;  it does not add it as multipart/form-data part.  I would avoid setting the Content-Type, forget about using getParts(), and just copy the request’s InputStream directly to a file.  Do *not* use a Reader for binary data!

Comment: @VGR You know it's quite hard to figure out everything by yourself, Thanks bro it just worked perfect ( '_' )